# loading values ajax response

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I am trying to fetch data in two different div's but the problem is that the second div is not responding for models when I pick an option for make in second div it chooses model from first div.how do I format this code.....

```
<div id="col1"> 
    <table width="20%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" id="tbsrch-engine14"> 
        <tr>
            <td height="10">
                <strong>Make:</strong> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="make" id="make" style="width: 155px;" onChange="get_models(this.value,'<?php echo $base_url ?>ajaxResponse/get_models.php')"> 
                    <option value="0">Any</option> 
                    <?php 
                        $query = "SELECT id, name FROM tbl_make";
                        $result = mysql_query($query);
                    ?> 
                    <?php while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?> 
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['id'].'-'.$row['name']?>">
                            <?php echo $row['name']?>
                        </option> 
                    <?php }?> 
                </select> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td height="40"> 
                <strong>Model:</strong> 
            </td> 
            <td> 
                <div id="models">
                    <select name="model" id="model"> 
                        <option value="0">Any</option>
                    </select> 
                </div> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
        </tbody> 
    </table> 
</div> 
<div id="col2">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" id="tbsrch-engine13"> 
        <tbody> 
            <tr> 
                <td height="10px;"> 
                    <select name="make" id="make" style="width: 155px;" onChange="get_models(this.value,'<?php echo $base_url ?>ajaxResponse/get_models.php')"> 
                        <option value="0">Any</option> 
                        <?php 
                        $query = "SELECT id, name FROM tbl_make ";
                        $result = mysql_query($query); ?> 
                        <?php while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?> 
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['id'].'-'.$row['name']?>"><?php echo $row['name']?></option>
                        <?php }?> 
                    </select> 
                </td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td> 
                    <div id="models"> 
                        <select name="model" id="model"> 
                            <option value="0">Any</option> 
                        </select>
                    </div> 
                </td> 
            </tr> 
        </tbody> 
    </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: What is it! Plase insert your code in human-readable form.

Comment: you are getting the same results because you re running the same query. try adding in where clauses to see the different responses.

Comment: @Jim can u plz explain

Comment: Please make your code snippet more understandable  so more people will try to help you. As it is right now, I doubt any one would flounder through so much un-formatted code.

Comment: you are running the same query "SELECT id, name FROM tbl_make " in both places.  If you are trying to get a model in the second div based on the selection of the first, then you need a where clause: "SELECT id, name FROM tbl_make WHERE id = ?????"

Comment: no i don't want to make a selection on the basis of first one.I want an independent selection in second div also

Comment: My bad.  is that not what you are getting?  I guess I am confused as to what it is you are trying to do. Can you post your ajaxResponse/get_models.php?

Comment: I just want that "model" in the second div work for the "make" selected in second div as when I select a make in second div then the model in the first div responds rather than of the second div.

Comment: <?php
include('autodealers.php');

$id = $_GET['id'];
$explode = explode('-',$id);
$id = $explode[0];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$db_prefix."model WHERE parent_id=".$id." ORDER BY make_name ASC";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

?>

<select name="model" id="model" style="width:155px;">
      <option value="0">Any</option>
 <?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['make_name']?></option>
<?php    
}?>
</select>

Comment: try changing your select id's.  they are currently both "make". then call the specific id $id=$_GET['make'] for example.

Comment: Do I need to change ajaxresponse?

Comment: Yes, see comment above. Or you could use an if statement to see which one is populated ie: $id=$_GET['make']; if $id=0 { $id=$_GET['model'];} then do your query